# Quick OSM error "not attribute 'get_bounding_box'"

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I'm new on Qgis.
I want to make query using Quick OSM pluging in QGIS 3.16. When I generate a query, it's returning me this error : `AttributeError: 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'get_bounding_box'`

But when I execute the query, it's working

Any idea what is happening ?

query :

```
[timeout:2500]
[maxsize:2000000000];
area[admin_level='6'][ref='90']->.area;
rel(pivot.area)->.rel;
(
node[highway](area.area);
node[highway](r.rel);
way[highway](area.area);
way[highway](r.rel);
rel[highway](area.area);
rel[highway](r.rel);
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

Comment: Please include an example query.

Comment: added in the post

Comment: I'm the developer of QuickOSM. This is an issue with the "generate query" button since a refactoring of the code. Can you open the ticket ? But the "Run query" works ;-)